# How to truncate UILabel without affecting line spacing?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, tvos

I need to truncate some multi-line labels with ellipsis. However, setting

```
mylabel.lineBreakMode = .ByTruncatingTail
mylabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
```

reduces line spacing. Is there a way to keep the original line spacing?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up truncating manually by whitespace which has two advantages:

1. words are not broken in the middle, and
2. `sizeToFit` sets height more precisely

(I need not-more-than certain height and the label has shadow so exact height is unwanted).